# How to tightly contain an SQL query result

Tags: sql

I'm writing an application that implements a message system through a 'memos' table in a database. The table has several fields that look like this:

```
id, date_sent, subject, senderid, recipients,message, status
```

When someone sends a new memo, it will be entered into the memos table. A memo can be sent to multiple people at the same time and the recipients userid's will be inserted into the 'recipients' field as comma separated values.

It would seem that an SQL query like this would work to see if a specific `userid` is included in a memo:

```
SELECT * FROM memos WHERE recipients LIKE %15%
```

But I'm not sure this is the right solution. If I use the SQL statement above, won't that return everything that "contains" 15? For example, using the above statement, user 15, 1550, 1564, 2015, would all be included in the result set (and those users might not actually be on the recipient list).

What is the best way to resolve this so that ONLY the user 15 is pulled in if they are in the recipient field instead of everything containing a 15? Am I misunderstanding the LIKE statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would be better off having your recipients as a child table of the memos table.  So your memo's table has a memo ID which is referenced by the child table as

```
MemoRecipients
-----
MemoRecipientId INT PRIMARY KEY, IDENTITY,
MemoId INT FK to memos NOT NULL
UserId INT NOT NULL
```

for querying specific memos from a user you would do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM MEMOS m
INNER JOIN memoRecipients mr on m.Id = mr.memoId
WHERE userId = 15
```

Comment: If you really needed to keep your current structure, you could ensure that even your last element in your userId list has a comma and check for %,15,% (I don't remember if comma needs to be escaped - but i would recommend against going this method as the answer provided is normalized

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how your application is exactly pulling these messages, but I imagine that better way would be creating a table `message_recepient`, which will represent many-to-many relationship between recipients and memos

```
id, memoId, recepientId
```

Then your application could pull messages like this

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM memos m inner join message_recepient mr on m.id = mr.memoId
WHERE recepientId = 15
```

This way you will get messages for the specific user. Again, don't know what your `status` field is for but if this is for `new/read/unread`, you could add in your where

```
and m.status = 'new'
Order by date_set desc
```

This way you could just accumulate messages, those that are new

Answer (score 2):

No, you aren't misunderstood, that's how `LIKE` works.. But to achieve what you want, it would be better not to combine the recipients into 1 field. Instead try to create separate table that saves the recipient list for each memo..

For me I will use below schema, for your need:

```
Table_Memo
id, date_sent, subject, senderid, message, status

Table_Recipient
id_memo FK Table_Memo(id), recipient
```

By doing so, if you want to get specific recipients from a memo, you can do such query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM Table_Memo a, Table_Recipient b 
WHERE a.id = "memo_id" AND a.id = b.id_memo AND b.recipient LIKE %15%
```